# Amplifying PWM to solenoid

Tags: power, amplifier, solenoid

I am driving a solenoid with a DRV103 (a driver for inductive loads by TI), but I need to allow more current to flow to the solenoid than the DRV103 can output. Initially, I tried a simple common source amplifier like this:

[image]

Ignore the component values, that's just to show topology. I couldn't get that to work though and wasn't seeing any amplification of the original signal. I feel like there's a really simple solution to this problem, but it's bugging me that I can't figure it out.
Also, is there anything special I need to take in account when trying to drive an inductive load with a MOSFET?

Comment: What is the purpose of PWM to solenoid? trying to make an linear flip flip? or just burn out your drivers? or trying to make the solenoid quieter? It's just a matter of Ohm's Law.

Comment: In your present circuit, the current will always flow through the coil and the diode, no matter what MOSFET is doing.  (How does that feel?)

Comment: The schematic doesn't bear any relationship to your question

Comment: @stevenvh, I think that is the heart of the question. It is not functional and to you the schematic makes no sense, but that is because that is what is stopping function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect the diode in parallel with the coil.  Leave the anode as is and move the cathode from the battery's neg terminal to the positive terminal.